# How can I add retention policy to AWS ElasticSearch created from CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I am sending logs from different environments to AWS ElasticSearch using fluentd. The AWS ES is created using a CloudFormation stack. How can do following two things:

1. Add a retention policy to keep all logs for 30 days.
2. Add retention policy as per environemts, say, env x for 60 days and env y for 7 days.

I could not find anything in CloudFormation stack to add retention policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no such feature in Cloudformation so far**. What can be done is to use Lambda with schedule to apply these retention rules.
The [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/curator.html) contains an example using lambda and the curator library.